# Date time filter on azure graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azureportal, audit-logging

How do I apply Date time filter on this particular Microsoft API:

`https://graph.windows.net/<tenantdomain>/activities/audit?api-version=beta`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter audit logs by Date, just try request below:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenantdomain>/activities/audit?api-version=beta&$filter=activityDate ge/le <timestamp>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if that is working, I added the following filter "filter=activityDate ge 2021-06-14T 11:00:00Z" and then I changed the year from 2021 to 2020, yet the number of events returned were the same

Comment: @ShambhaviRai  try `$filter=activityDate ge 2021-06-14T11:00:00Z`, just remove the empty character

Comment: @ShambhaviRai - It is `$filter` and not `filter` (notice the `$` sign).

Comment: Yeah the filter seems to be working, it returns a maximum of 1045 entries for one page, when I narrowed down the search it seems to be working just fine